# python: inversion of a division without remainder

Tags: python, math, operator-keyword, division

Having a code like:

```
import time
result = time.time()//interval
```

Is it possible to know the `time.time()` that generated the result knowing `result` and `interval`?

Comment: Since you're using integer division then the answer is no, the function loses the decimal-information.

Comment: `4//4`, `5//4` and `6//4` all give you `1`. It's impossible to know what number you started with unless you keep note of it.

Comment: @khelwood thank you. very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you olny need to multiply both sides by `interval`

```
time_used = result * interval
```

However, because you have integer division, you will know the time to an `interval` precision. That is you will always get a lower bound on time.

Comment: Thank you. Do I get **always** the lower value of the interval  in this way?

Comment: Yes, I added this to the answer.